# Question from first chapter of Markov Chains and Mixing Times

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I am currently self studying Markov Chains and Mixing Times by Levin and Peres. I am a bit confused at a little above halfway point on page 11.

It goes as follows: Let $x\in \mathcal{X}$ be an arbitrary state of a Markov Chain. We will closely examine the average time the chains spends at each state in between visits to $z$. To this end, we define \begin{align*} \pi(y):&=\mathbf{E}_z \text{(number of visits to $y$ before returning to $x$)}\\  &=\sum_{t=0}^\infty \mathbf{P}_z\{X_t=y,\tau_z^+>t\}.\end{align*}

Here, we are investigating existence of the stationary distribution, **but I do not understand how we can express this $\pi(y)$ in the way that is shown on the second line with the sum? How do we know the expected number of visits to a different state before returning to the orginal state can be represented as this infinite sum?** Any help would be greatly appreciated so I can understand this statement. Thanks.

Also, here $\tau_z^+$ is the first return time from state $z$ back to state $z$.

Answer (score 1):

The number $N(y,z)$ of visits to $y$ before returning to $z$ can be written as
\begin{equation*}
N(y,z) = \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} 1_{\{X_{t} = y, \tau^{+}_{z} > t\}}.
\end{equation*}
Therefore, by linearity of expectation (plus monotone convergence),
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}_{z}(N(y,z)) = \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}_{z}(1_{\{X_{t} = y,\tau_{z}^{+} > t\}}) = \sum_{t = 1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}_{z}(\{X_{t} = y, \tau_{z}^{+} > t\}).
\end{equation*}